# On Fredholm alternative for Neumann conditions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, sp.spectral-theory, parabolic-pde, linear-pde

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded Lipschitz domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $f \in L^2(\Omega)$. It is well known that if $\lambda$ is a Dirichlet Laplacian eigenvalue, then the equation $$\begin{cases}
-\Delta u=\lambda u+f\quad &\mbox{in $\Omega$}\\
u=0\quad &\mbox{on $\partial \Omega$}
 \end{cases}$$
admits a weak solution in $H^1_0(\Omega)$ if and only if $f$ is perpendicular (in $L^2$ scalar product) to any eigenfunction of $\lambda$.

Now let us consider a similar problem with Neumann condition. That is, let $\mu$ be a Neumann Laplacian eigenvalue and consider the existence of the equation
$$\begin{cases}
-\Delta u=\mu u+f\quad &\mbox{in $\Omega$}\\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu}=0\quad &\mbox{on $\partial \Omega$}
 \end{cases}$$
Is it true that a weak solution in $H^1(\Omega)$ exists if and only if $f$ is perpendicular to any eigenfunction of $\mu$?

I know this is a necessary condition, since for any eigenfunction $v$ of $\mu$, from the second Green identity we have that
$$\int_{\Omega}\Delta u v\, dx-\int_{\Omega}\Delta v u\, dx=0,$$and thus $\int_{\Omega}fv\, dx=0$. I'm not sure whether this is a sufficient condition. It seems that the functional analysis method does not work. In the Dirichlet case, the natural space is the Hilbert space $H^1_0(\Omega)$. I don't know how to do the proof for Neumann boundary data. Any comment and ideas would be fully appreciated!

Comment: This works for every self-adjoint operator $A$ with a compact resolvent. Write $Ax=\sum_n \lambda_n (x,e_n)e_n$ to see that $(\lambda_k-A)x=y$ has a solution if and only if $(y,e_k)=0$ and $(x,e_i)=(y,e_i)/(\lambda_k-\lambda_i)$.